# Laravel 5 Eloquent Condition With Pivot

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have the Following models relationship.

```
promotions: [id, title, description]

sectors: [id, name]

promotion_sector: [promotion_id, sector_id]
```

---

```
class Promotion extends Model {
    public function sectors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector');
    }
}
```

I want to get the promotions which are in given sectors.

For example,

All the promotions in sector A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which type of relationship you are using. I presume it to be `Many-To-Many` Relationship.

So here's the code you can try:

```
$result = DB::table('promotion_sector')
          ->join('promotions', 'id', '=', 'promotion_sector.promotion_id')
          ->join('sectors', 'id', '=', 'promotion_sector.sector_id')
          ->select('sectors.name AS sector_name')
          ->get();

dd( $result );
```

And if you are asking for the input from the user:

```
$result = DB::table('promotion_sector')
              ->join('promotions', 'id', '=', 'promotion_sector.promotion_id')
              ->join('sectors', 'id', '=', 'promotion_sector.sector_id')
              ->where( 'sectors.name', '=', $request->input('name_of_the_field') )
              ->select('sectors.name AS sector_name')
              ->get();

dd( $result );
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all sectors associated with a promotion.

Try this:

```
class Promotion extends Model {

    public function sectors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sector', 'promotion_sector', 'promotion_id', 'sector_id');
     }
}
```

To verify, try this in artisan tinker:

```
$pro = App\Promotion::find(1);
$pro->sectors;
$pro;
```

You will get the list of all sectors associated with Promotion with Id 1.

To do the opposite, that you have asked in the question.

You need to do this:

```
class Sector extends Model {

    public function promotions() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Promotion', 'promotion_sector', 'sector_id', 'promotion_id');
     }
}
```

To verify, try this in artisan tinker:

```
$sec = App\Sector::find(1);
$sec->promotions;
$sec;
```

You will get the list of all the promotions associated with sector with Id 1.